# Glassfish replaces managed bean with fully qualified name with just class name

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-3

I'm currently adding functionality to a web platform written in Java and using GlassFish 3.1 as the server. This is a highly complex platform in terms of maintenance and my efforts with googling and reading through documentation were fruitless.

When deploying I get the following warning:

```
WARNING: JSF1074: Managed bean named 'SomeClass' has already been registered.
Replacing existing managed bean class type com.example.package.SomeClass with SomeClass.
```

That leads to the exception below when the web page is opened. My guess is this happens because the managed bean was registered without the package name.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class SomeClass
```

The bean is annotated the following way

```
@ManagedBean(name="SomeClass")
@SessionScoped
public class SomeClass { ... }
```

If I undeploy, restart Glassfish and deploy again, **sometimes** the fully qualified managed bean is registered and the problem (temporarily) solved. This just adds to my confusion.

So, my question is: what could be causing GlassFish to replace a managed bean with the fully qualified name with another using just the class name?

Comment: Do you really need `@ManagedBean`?

Comment: Yes. That decision precedes me, though. By the way, it's a JSF Managed Bean.

Comment: Please add an example of the page where you are using the ManagedBean.